# rusttype get text width for Font

Tags: image, image-processing, rust, fonts

### Motive

I'm trying to render a `String` of dynamic length on an [`Image`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/enum.DynamicImage.html) using [`imageproc`](https://docs.rs/imageproc).

### Question

I need a method or function to calculate the width of the text when rendered using a specific `Font` and `Scale` to center the text on the image.

### Additional Notes

[`rusttype`](https://docs.rs/rusttype) is the font library used by imageproc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rusttype repo contains an example ([examples/image.rs](https://gitlab.redox-os.org/redox-os/rusttype/-/blob/master/dev/examples/image.rs)), which measures the bounds of a line of text and renders it to an image. *Basically what you're searching, besides the centering part.*

```rust
// rusttype = "0.9.2"
use rusttype::{point, Font, Scale};

let v_metrics = font.v_metrics(scale);

let glyphs: Vec<_> = font.layout(text, scale, point(0.0, 0.0)).collect();
let glyphs_height = (v_metrics.ascent - v_metrics.descent).ceil() as u32;
let glyphs_width = {
    let min_x = glyphs
        .first()
        .map(|g| g.pixel_bounding_box().unwrap().min.x)
        .unwrap();
    let max_x = glyphs
        .last()
        .map(|g| g.pixel_bounding_box().unwrap().max.x)
        .unwrap();
    (max_x - min_x) as u32
};
```

I didn't like always needing to collect into a `Vec`, while also needing to use non-integer sizes. So in the past I created my own version of what's *essentially* in the example.

One important note, is that the position passed to layout doesn't *really* matter, when you only need the size. However, if you actually need to render the glyphs, then the position is important as otherwise the result will contain aliasing artifacts.

```rust
// rusttype = "0.9.2"
use rusttype::{point, Font, Scale};

fn measure_line(font: &Font, text: &str, scale: Scale) -> (f32, f32) {
    let width = font
        .layout(text, scale, point(0.0, 0.0))
        .map(|g| g.position().x + g.unpositioned().h_metrics().advance_width)
        .last()
        .unwrap_or(0.0);

    let v_metrics = font.v_metrics(scale);
    let height = v_metrics.ascent - v_metrics.descent + v_metrics.line_gap;

    (width, height)
}
```

If the text has multiple lines, then you'd manually need to use [`.lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) on the string, and then sum the line heights and line spacing.

Comment: Just moving ```.last()``` a line up will improve performance for large strings.